# Request factory entity inheritance and proxy interface

Tags: java, gwt, inheritance, requestfactory

If I have an entity extending some other entity, I can't specify some setter methods in my proxy interface. Eclipse tells me there is no matching method in my Entity class. Thats true because it is in the super class. Can't request factory handle that inheritance or is it just some configuration issue in my eclipse. (I set up the annotation processing stuff for that request factory validation)

Here the example code: 
My entity. Has no methods but should inherit them from the superclass:

```
@Entity
public class Entity extend AbstractEntity{

}
```

The superclass. Holds the setter and getter:

```
public class AbstractEntity{
    VoteType getType(){ return null; }
    public void setType(VoteType vote) {}
}
```

My proxy interface. Eclipse marks the setType() method with an error. (But not the getType()?)

```
@ProxyFor(value=Entity.class)
public interface EntityProxy extends EntityProxy{

    public VoteType getType();
    public void setType(VoteType vote);

}
```

Comment: That **should** work.

Answer (score -1):

According to the [docs](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideRequestFactory.html), your Entity class should have the @Entity annotation and your EntityProxy interface should extend the EntityProxy interface.